# Can elements with 'display: none' impact on "Update Layer Tree" time in chrome?

Tags: javascript, android, html, performance, mobile

I have performance issue.
Chrome timeline shows that 'Update layer tree' takes too long (279ms on mobile device Samsung Galaxy S3)
Could a bunch of `div` styled with `diaply:none` cause it?

Comment: Using the new `contain` property can also help with performance (new browsers only though).

Answer (score 0):

No. Elements with `display: none` are not included in the render tree, so they're not around to affect the layer tree. This is assuming that they always have `display: none`. If you toggle that on/off, then it can affect the layer tree.

Comment: Could you help me figure out what has impact on "Update layer tree" duration?